# Execute Code on successful authentication Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I want to execute code on successful authentication to add certain roles to my user object:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${ad.domain}")
    private String AD_DOMAIN;

    @Value("${ad.url}")
    private String AD_URL;

    @Autowired
    UserRoleComponent userRoleComponent;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        this.logger.info("Verify logging level"); //works
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

                        userRoleComponent.testIt();
                        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/");

                    }
                })
            .and()
                .httpBasic();

        http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN,
                AD_URL);
        provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

So I tried to add a new `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to insert code to be executed in a component (this is where the roles should be added then).

In my `UserRoleController`:

```
@Component
public class UserRoleComponent {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserRoleComponent.class);

    public void testIt() {
        this.logger.info("=============== User Authentication ==============");
        System.out.println("================ User Authentication ================");

    }

}
```

Now sadly when I login successfully there is no output printed. How can I solve this issue?

Edit: I verified the loggin level is correct and the `system.out.println` does not work also.

Comment: I tried this and it works. Have you tried to debug your code? set a break point

Comment: @SimonMartinelli That's strange. Did you also use an LDAP-Authentication? I use the default login page that is provided in `Spring-Security`

Comment: I have my own but the code is the same

Comment: I also tried adding a `System.out.println` in `onAuthenticationSuccess` (without a method-call inbetween) but that's also not printing... So it seems that he does not execute that `onAuthenticationSuccess` - did I overwrite that with another dependency I added afterwards? Could that be possible?

Comment: try remove basic() and http.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);